# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at onFailure

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am new to React and I am getting this error - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at onFailure

```
 const onFailure = (error) => {
      let err = error.response.data.error;
      this.setState({ isLoading: false, errors: err });
    };
```

Comment: This is a Javascript thing, not React. And it's pretty self-explanatory,  `error.response` is undefined, and you're trying to access `error.response.data`. Print the `error` and see what it's shape is

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory.

In your code `let err = error.response.data.error;`
The value of `error.response` is undefined.

So the error is occurred when you are trying to access "data" from an undefined item.

in ES6,
You can modify your code like below,

```
const onFailure = (error) => {
      let err = error?.response?.data?.error;
      this.setState({ isLoading: false, errors: err });
    };
```